# Negative GetLastWin32Error()

Tags: c#, debugging, winapi, getlasterror

I am wondering how to debug (or what to do actually) a negative value of `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`?

I have working on my PC peace of code, suddenly it doesn't works on another PC and I have no clue what to do, because I don't know what errors is there.

Here is code (essential part I think):

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetupDiChangeState(IntPtr deviceInfoSet, [In] ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData);

// and then somewhere
if (!SetupDiChangeState(info, ref device))
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error({0}) SetupDiChangeState", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
```

Exception text on other PC is

> Error(-536870389) SetupDiChangeState

It's not listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx).

Comment: `unchecked((uint) Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())` is your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error(-536870389) SetupDiChangeState

It is `0xE000020B`, and perhaps corresponds to `ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST`.

See your `DIFxAPI.h`.

Comment: Where do I get that `ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVINST`? I see it is possible to convert `int` to hex: `0xFFFFFFFFxxxxxxxx`, right?

Comment: I'd say vice versa: cast it to `uint`, and then see the hex value.

Comment: @Sinatr: You cannot *convert* an `int` to hex. Hex is a positional numeral system, that controls how a value is **displayed**. An `int`, on the other hand, is a data type of your programming language C#. The data type controls which operations are available, storage layout, range, etc. The data type is unrelated to the stored value in a human-readable representation.

Comment: @IInspectable, I don't know what you mean, but in my example to see `E000020B` instead of `-536870389` it was simply enough to specify `X`: `string.Format("Error({0:X}) SetupDiChangeState", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())`

Comment: @Sinatr: That's a conversion from `int` to `string`. There is no conversion from `int` to hex. You should also consider using the format specifier `{0:X8}` instead: `GetLastError` returns a `DWORD`, an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: You can use the [ERRLOOK utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akay62ya.aspx), which is available from the Tools menu as Error Lookup

Comment: @JacobSeleznev Did you try it with the given code? My one says "Message not found". (I'm not very surprised, since this value does not belong to regular error codes.)

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't convenient for your program to output the error in hexadecimal, you can also convert the error code using `calc.exe`.

- First, go into programmer mode.
- Select "Hex" and enter `100000000` (one and eight zeroes).
- Go back to "Dec" and subtract the absolute value of your error code, in this case `536870389`.
- Go back to "Hex" to see the hexadecimal error code, in this case `E000020B`.

Comment: Thanks, noticed that after @AlexD answer. It's even easier, enter negative value there as "Dec", hit "Hex" and ignore `0xffffff` part at the beginning. Confusing part is why `Marshal` return `int`, other confusing part is lack of normal msdn reference for all codes. Currently I am searching for them in google by entering "#define blabla", where blabla is hex-code of error. Then I know constant name (to example, `SILENCE_MUST_BE_HEARED`) and only then I am able to find something to give me clues what is wrong. Entering `-536870389` into google is a fail...